# CSS table display modes layout

Tags: jquery, css-tables

> [View JSFiddle >](http://jsfiddle.net/kkBRE/31/)

I have a layout that I used jQuery to make ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkBRE/31/)) and I have a feeling that a lot of code can be replaced with `display: table`, `display: table-cell` and `display: table-row`. However I've never been able to figure it out.

`HTML`

```
<menu>
    <command class="less" />
    <command class="more" />
    <div></div>
    <command class="save" />
    <command class="vote" />
    <div></div>
    <command class="send" />
    <command class="exit" />
</menu>
```

[image: Action Bar]

You can see it functioning with the jQuery [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kkBRE/31/), or without it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/843cP/).

> Thanks ahead of time for any help.

PS: I don't want to change the element types for my own reasons, so please leave the `<menu>` and `<command>` elements. I only need help with CSS

Comment: does "http://jsfiddle.net/kkBRE/31/" represent the correct visual output?  If so, are you just looking for ways to change the jQuery & CSS to use the display:table values?

Answer (score 0):

I added some HTML elements to make this function using only CSS, no JavaScript.

Also, a couple of the existing CSS attributes I removed by preceding the attribute with an ***X***. Example:

```
menu > div {
    Xheight: 40px;
    Xfloat: left;
}
```

Link to [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jim31415/XZuXd/).